# Base64 implementation is not giving the desired result

Tags: python, base64

I've followed the following [site](http://fm4dd.com/programming/base64/base64_algorithm.shtm) instructions in order to implement base64 encoding.

Here's my code:

```
from bitarray import bitarray
from bitarray.util import ba2int

base64mapping = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcd\
efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"

testString1 = "49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c\
696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d"

stringBits = bitarray()
# We create an unitialized bitarray
stringBits.frombytes(testString1.encode('utf-8'))
# We convert the string to bits

b64stringList = []  # To store the corresponding b64 chars

for sequence in range(0, len(stringBits), 6):
    # We scan the bitarray 6 bits at a time
    b64stringList += base64mapping[(ba2int(stringBits[sequence:sequence+6]))]
    # We store the corresponding b64 char into b64stringlist

print(''.join(b64stringList))  # Lets see the result
```

The testString1 was taken from the [cryptopals set 1 - challenge 1](https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/1) which tells me the result should be:

> SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t

However, my implementation gives another result:

> NDkyNzZkMjA2YjY5NmM2YzY5NmU2NzIwNzk2Zjc1NzIyMDYyNzI2MTY5NmUyMDZjNjk2YjY1MjA2MTIwNzA2ZjY5NzM2ZjZlNmY3NTczMjA2ZDc1NzM2ODcyNmY2ZjZk

I checked against Wikipedia's [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Examples) and I get the same output sans the padding at the end (TODO).

What I am doing wrong or missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the site, the task is to convert the `hex` to `base64`.

Your encoding, seems to be working correctly as the library `base64` outputs the same as your result when running it directly over the hex value

```
t = b'49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d'

base64.b64encode(t)
b'NDkyNzZkMjA2YjY5NmM2YzY5NmU2NzIwNzk2Zjc1NzIyMDYyNzI2MTY5NmUyMDZjNjk2YjY1MjA2MTIwNzA2ZjY5NzM2ZjZlNmY3NTczMjA2ZDc1NzM2ODcyNmY2ZjZk'
```

Using `binascii` we can convert the `hex` value your originally have to readable text by using `unhexlify()`

```
binascii.unhexlify(t)
#b"I'm killing your brain like a poisonous mushroom"
```

---

Given this information it would be best to take the approach that what you're storing is not a `string` but a `hex` representation of the `string` itself.

Due to this we will need to convert your `hex` to the readable string before encoding it.

When we pass the resulting string to `base64` your output matches the expected output in the link.

```
base64.b64encode(binascii.unhexlify(t))
#b'SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t'
```